# Android Studio - Erro na chamada de Activity

Tags: android

Desenvolvi um aplicativo(jogo) com botões que chamam telas.
A ideia é assim:

- Tela 1 - inicio
- Tela 2 - escolhe personagem
- Tela 3 - conhece objeto1
- Tela 4 - brinca com objeto1
- Tela 5 - conhece objeto2
- Tela 6 - brinca com objeto2
- Tela 7 - conhece objeto3
- .... segue o padrão..

Quando vou fazer os testes no celular, após determinado número de telas (7) o aplicativo para de funcionar.

A base de todas as telas (Activity) são semelhantes (Telas 3,5,7 ; Telas 4,6,8), muda alguns itens. Já analisei os códigos e não consigo entender.

Fiz alguns testes: começando de determinadas telas e mudando a ordem das telas. Mas o problema continua, quando chega em um determinado numero de avanços de telas, o aplicativo trava, aperto "Ok" e a tela é reiniciada.

Quem puder me ajudar, agradeço.

Comment: manda se aparece  alguma coisa no log, e o que aparece no log,quando o app trava

Comment: Na verdade ele trava no celular. Quando faço os testes no aparelho

Comment: ue, espeta o cabo usb no celular, e emula o app,vai gerar um logde erro, em android monitor,quando o app parar,mas acredito que possa ser algum problema de memória,talvez

Comment: O que pode estar acontecendo é um sobrecarga de memória. Não há uma possibilidade de você fechar a activity anterior assim que abre uma nova?

Comment: Coloca o print de uma activity ai

Comment: @OtoCampos teu comentário foi TOP. Eu resolvi colocando um finish() após a chamada da nova tela. Mas fazendo novos testes, ele voltou a travar. Acredito que esteja relacionado com o Media Player, quando o usuário conhece o objeto, ele clica e um som é emitido usando setLooping(true). Dai ele clica no objeto e o som para. Entretanto, depois de alguns objetos, o aplicativo trava, mas o som continua. Alguma dica?

Comment: @BonecoSinforoso era exatamente isso, resolvi com finish()

Comment: Pessoal, estou de volta. No meu celular ele está funcionando bem todas as fases (telas). Mas quando fui colocar em outros celulares, o aplicativo volta a dar problema. Ele para de funcionar na mesma tela em que parava no meu celular. Ao parar, ela volta para tela inicial, acredito que prova que todas as telas anteriores foram finalizadas. Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)Então realmente voce esta tendo um problema com memória,mantenha esse esquema do finish após o startactivity.

2)Trabalhe com os estados da sua activity.coloque este código no seu ondestroy, ele limpara a memória que seu app esta consumindo com midias quando o usuário sair da palicação.

```
 @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if( mp!= null ){
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        mp= null;
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Por consequência aplique este código conforme você for usando o som na sua aplicação e o som for finalizado,

```
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        mp= null;
        }
        });
```

Seria interessante você também inserir este código no seu build.gradle:
Ele aumentará o capacidade de consumo de memória da sua aplicação,use-o com moderação,faça testes.....
Ele aumenta a capacidade de armazenamento da sua memória heap, que é aonde o java cria os objetos da aplicação.
    android{
     //....
     dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }
}

Comment: Pessoal valeu pela força. @otocampos sua dica foi show de bola. Resolvi o problema com ela.

Comment: Vlw irmão,se puder da um up na resposta,abraço

Answer (score 0):

Seu problema está em ficar empilhando Activity sobre Activity.

Comece a usar Fragments para esses casos OU então, a cada tela nova aberta, você vai dando um `finish()` para finalizar a anterior (caso não dê problema na sequencia da UX).