# Android Studio - Aplicativo para de funcionar em outros celulares

Tags: android

neste post aqui:
[Android Studio - Erro na chamada de Activity](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/234807/android-studio-erro-na-chamada-de-activity)
contei o problema que estava enfrentando.

Resumindo...

Desenvolvi um aplicativo(jogo) com botões que chamam telas. A ideia é assim:

Tela 1 - inicio
Tela 2 - escolhe personagem
Tela 3 - conhece objeto1
Tela 4 - brinca com objeto1
Tela 5 - conhece objeto2
Tela 6 - brinca com objeto2
Tela 7 - conhece objeto3
.... segue o padrão..

Resolvi finalizando as activities e liberando as variavais media player.

No meu celular ele está funcionando bem todas as fases (telas). Mas quando fui colocar em outros celulares, o aplicativo volta a dar problema. Ele para de funcionar na mesma tela em que parava no meu celular. Ao parar, ela volta para tela inicial, acredito que prova que todas as telas anteriores foram finalizadas. Não consigo entender o que está acontecemdo.
 Help! –

Comment: É extremamente importante você verificar as versões do Android no qual você está tentando executar seu app. Não tem, de forma nenhuma, a gente saber o problema só com sua história.

Comment: Entendo. No meu celular a versão é 5.0.2 e o outro de teste é 6.0.1

Comment: Então, por exemplo, no 6.0.1 tem o sistema de permissão em tempo real diferente do 5.0 abaixo. Verifique se há algo relacionado as permissões.